# Using hasMany in grails and postgresql

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a **postgresql** database that has this column structure:

```
Author
  id
  name

Book
  id
  name
  author_id
```

And Groovy Domain Classes that repressent those tables:

```
class Author {
   static hasMany = [ books : Book ]

   Integer id
   String name
}   

class Book {
   static belongsTo = Author

   Integer id
   Integer project_id
   String name
}
```

My main goal to get a list of books from a author instance.

```
author = Author.get( 1 ) // gets a author
author.books // must return a list of books.
```

But this does not work. Is there something glaringly obvious I'm doing wrong?

**note** I've got lots of Ruby/Rails experience and zull Java/Groovy experience.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should remove the "Integer id" declarations - Grails adds id and version properties for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Book` class to:

```
class Book {
   static belongsTo = [authors: Author]

   static mapping = {
       authors column: 'author_id'
   } 

   Integer id
   Integer project_id
   String name
}
```

If you don't specify the `mapping` like that, GORM will create, resp., expect, a JOIN table by default.

(BTW, domain classes are automatically provided with a "virtual" `id` property (of type `Long` I think, translating to `bigint` in PostgreSQL). It's not necessary to specify it manually, but it also won't harm.)

---

**EDIT**: Updated as per the questioners comments:

If a book can *really* have just one author, you'd state in the `Book` class:

```
Author author
static belongsTo = [author: Author]

static mapping = { author column: 'author_id' }
```

The GORM documentation on one-to-many relations can be found [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.1.2%20One-to-many).

Comment: I will try this, but a book has one author and a author may have many books.... looks like your setting up a `book.authors` ?

Comment: also, could you point me to documentation that mentions that? ( becuase the documentation on grails.org doesn't or at least... not on the surface )

Comment: Please see the updated answer. - It might be always a good idea to define a database in `create-drop` or `update` mode (in an additional, experimental, project) to see which database schema gets created actually.

Comment: robbbert - if you want to see what the schema definition is for your current domain classes just run 'grails schema-export' and look at target/ddl.sql